# Problem with service drop

Tags: electrical, wiring, utilities

I have overhead wire providing my two phase electric service.  The line from the pole appears to be relatively new and the splice connectors appear to be in good condition as well.

However, there is little to no slack to provide a drip loop and the two conductor wires appear to be rubbing against each other.  Even worse it seems, the cable jackets all seem to be cracking and splitting *after* the splices (but before the meter).

Who is responsible for this section of the drop? The property owner or the utility company?

Obviously this needs immediate attention and I appreciate your help on this in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of who's responsible money wise, you should call your utility company's repair line now.  If it's before the meter, they need to be involved in disconnecting the service either way.

Generally they will send someone out to inspect it and let you know if it needs repairs.  They'll also tell you whether you need to pay for the repairs or not...but either way they need to look at it right away, so it makes no difference in what you need to do.

Different hydro companies have different rules, but generally the demarcation point (where it goes from being their problem to your problem) is either at the top of the service stack, or at the terminals on the house's side of the meter.  Everything before there is their job to fix.

Comment: I understand that the utility company will need to be involved but I am not the property owner - I am a tenant.  Seeking input on the responsibility of parties involved before establishing contact.  PS thank you for your answer!

Comment: @gabriel even better - either way you don't need to foot the bill.  If you think it poses a significant hazard (and if the insulation is cracking, it very much could - those wires don't have circuit breakers, they keep going until something breaks) I would call your hydro company's emergency number and talk to them.

Comment: Thank you Grant, I have called the emergency number.  They are supposed to inspect the drop tonight.  My concern is largely financial because of rent concessions made in lieu of work done in recent months.  But I suppose there is little point in worrying about that now if the property is in significant danger of a fire.

Comment: I would, uh, call the landlord.

Comment: I very much doubt there is any legal way a landlord can rent out a place that is unsafe.  The landlord may or may not be happy if he has to pay.  But he would be less happy if his tenant died in a horrible electrical fire and the house burnt to the ground.  The hydro company will figure out if its safe or not, and go from there.  The reason I said call hydro not the landlord is scummy ones wont care...and you get left in a deathtrap.  The hydro company might decide its ok, but better safe than dead.

Comment: They just left, no significant problem noted.  I would like there to be a better drip loop and a clean connection at the splices (the dielectric grease was oozing from the connectors, giving the appearance of the cracks). But, I will sleep better tonight!

Comment: @Grant From the splices to the meter is the homeowner's responsibility (in my case anyway).  Thanks for your quick answer!